# Unable to Scroll to Div using <a href="#"> [React,react-scrollspy]

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using this library https://github.com/makotot/react-scrollspy to get the scroll to div effect.However after following the documentation ,I don't seem to get it working.Code :

```
<RewardContainer>
                <div className="pageWrapper">
                    <div className="rewardInfoWrapper">
                        <div className="tabsContainer">
                            <div>
                                <Scrollspy
                                    items={[
                                        "section-1",
                                        "section-2",
                                        "section-3"
                                    ]}
                                    currentClassName="is-current"
                                >
                                    <li>
                                        <a
                                            href="#section-1"
                                            className="c-side-nav__link"
                                        >
                                            Streak
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a
                                            href="#section-2"
                                            className="c-side-nav__link"
                                        >
                                            Gems
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a
                                            href="#section-3"
                                            className="c-side-nav__link"
                                        >
                                            Xp Points
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </Scrollspy>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="columnContainer">
                            <div className="tabInfo">
                                <div>
                                    <div id="section-1">
                                            <p>
                                                This is Section 1
                                            </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="section-2">
                                            <p>
                                                This is Section 2
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    <div id="section-3">
                                            <p>
                                                This is Section 3
                                            </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </RewardContainer>
```

The issue is ,my a href="#id" tag reloads the browser and treats id as a route instead of scrolling to that div's id.For instance,clicking on the third li element reloads the browser with http://localhost:7000/#section-3 in the url.